Goland go routines randomly stop with no error reported
I am running into weird issues with running go routines, I have a set of go routines, each handles one "gas pump" but they do die after some time, with all the data inspection I could not find any difference between working go routines data and the data that may have stopped the routine from going. Theres zero error report or anything else, the program just keeps going.
func pumpOperation(pump *Pump, pumpQueue *EntryQueue, registerQueues *[]*RegisterQueue, outputs *[]Car, maxCarCount int64, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    for {
        //fmt.Printf("Pump type: %s service alive\n", pumpQueue.Type)

        //fmt.Printf("strring sim: %d\n", strings.Compare(pump.Type, pumpQueue.Type))
        if pump.IsOccupied == false && strings.Compare(pump.Type, pumpQueue.Type) == 0 {
            pump.Mutex.Lock()
            select {
            case car := <-pumpQueue.Queue: // Receive a car from the queue
                { // Check if the pump is free (nil car)

                    pump.CurrentCar = car
                    pump.CurrentCar.PumpEntry = time.Now()
                    pump.IsOccupied = true

                    //fmt.Printf("Car %d of type %s entered %s pump at %v.\n", pump.CurrentCar.ID, pump.CurrentCar.Type, pump.Type, pump.CurrentCar.PumpEntry)

                    // Simulate service time
                    // print the pump service time
                    //fmt.Printf("Pump %s, Service time from %dms to %dms\n", pump.Type, pump.ServiceMin, pump.ServiceMax)

                    serviceTime := rand.Intn(pump.ServiceMax-pump.ServiceMin+1) + pump.ServiceMin

                    //fmt.Printf("Service time: %d\n", serviceTime)
                    time.Sleep(time.Duration(serviceTime) * time.Millisecond)

                    
                }
            default:

                // No car in queue, pump waits
                fmt.Printf("No car in queue, %s pump waits\n", pump.Type)
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond) // Reduce CPU usage, adjust timing as needed
                pump.Mutex.Unlock()
                continue
            }
            pump.Mutex.Unlock()
        }
    }
}

This is how I call the go routines from the main function:
for i := range pumps {
        pump := &pumps[i] // Get a pointer to the pump instance

        wg.Add(1)
        go pumpOperation(pump, pumpQueues[pump.Type], &registerQueues, &cars, config.Cars.Count, &wg)
    }

I will be providing more code if it is necessarry I am also very new to go and would appreaciate help, please...
I did use print statements to verify that the go routines indeed stop responding.
Also tried similiar approach without using mutex and the issue persisted.
Also tried creating only 1 go routine that handles all the data and it also does crash.

pump.IsOccupied is never reset. You are not holding the Mutex while reading IsOccupied and Type. If pump.Mutex is not a pointer you are copying the Mutexes in main. Why do you need a Mutex if there is one goroutine per pump?

Run your code with the race detector. When you encounter a deadlock you can use the full stack trace to see where every goroutine is blocked.
